# How to traverse all files in a directory one by one using c#?

Tags: c#

I want to traverse all the files in a directory recursively one by one using c#.
also i need to check the modified date and created date of that specific file.
I have used Directory.GetFiles(), but it gives me list of files in single instance.
I want files should be traverse one by one like findfirstfile, findnextfile in c++

Comment: [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0)

Comment: There is no built-in function for that, you were on the right path with `Directory.GetFiles()`. You need to access each file seperately and get their attributes, i.e. by using the [FileInfo class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @Chr `Directory.GetFiles()` returns strings, but `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` returns FileInfos, on which you can inspect dates and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> I want files should be traverse one by one like findfirstfile, findnextfile in c++

Then you call those via P/Invoke, see https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.findfirstfile and https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.findnextfile.

But why? You're using managed code, use a friendlier API and the accompanying paradigms. Such as [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-5.0), which on Windows calls the same Win32 APIs.

If you insist on using the procedural paradigm, then you do this:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
var enumerator = files.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var file = enumerator.Current;
    // do something with file
}
```

Why though? The idiomatic way for that is a `foreach`, which does the same but with some compiler magic that keeps the code readable:

```
foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles())
{
   // do something with file 
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm specifically not answering the recursive part of the question, as that's been answered in at least a dozen duplicates, I'm responding to the FindFirstFile() remarks.